# How to get a day weather forecast for a list of cities using R?

Tags: r, http, httprequest, openweathermap

I tried to get the date frame using this function but I cant get it right, as I am trying to Write a function to return a data frame containing 5-day weather forecasts for a list of cities but I do  not know what is missing. Here I using openweathermap.org for the weather data.
Thanks.

```
# Get forecast data for a given city list
get_weather_forecaset_by_cities <- function(city_names){
    df <- data.frame()
    for (city_name in city_names){
        # Forecast API URL
        forecast_url <- 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast'
        # Create query parameters
        forecast_query <- list(q = city_name, appid = "b0847c4a1554d3c63d46d0e9249500f0", units="metric")
        # Make HTTP GET call for the given city
        responce<- GET(forecast_url, query= forecast_query)
        json_result <- content(responce, as="parsed")
        
        # Note that the 5-day forecast JSON result is a list of lists. You can print the reponse to check the results
         result <- json_result
        
        # Loop the json result
        for(result in results) {
            city <- c(city, city_name)
            
        }
        
        # Add the R Lists into a data frame
         # $weather is also a list with one element, its $main element indicates the weather status such as clear or rain
city  <- c(result$city$name)       
weather <- c( result$weather[[1]]$main)
# Get Visibility
visibility <- c( result$visibility)
# Get current temperature 
temp <- c(result$main$temp)
# Get min temperature 
temp_min <- c( result$main$temp_min)
# Get max temperature 
temp_max <- c( result$main$temp_max)
# Get pressure
pressure <- c( result$main$pressure)
# Get humidity
humidity <- c(result$main$humidity)
# Get wind speed
wind_speed <- c( result$wind$speed)
# Get wind direction
wind_deg <- c( result$wind$deg)
weather_data_frame <- data.frame(city,
                                 weather,
                                 visibility, 
                                 temp, 
                                 temp_min, 
                                 temp_max, 
                                 pressure, 
                                 humidity, 
                                 wind_speed, 
                                 wind_deg)

    }
    
    # Return a data frame
    return(df)
    
}

cities <- c("Seoul", "Washington, D.C.", "Paris", "Suzhou")
cities_weather_df <- get_weather_forecaset_by_cities(cities)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you do not know what is missing for your problem, how do we?  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  As piece of general advice, I would write a fuction that gets the information you need for a single city, taking the city (name or id) as its first argument.  Then I would use `lapply` to call that function on a vector of cities.  I'd then use `rbind()` or `dplyr::bind_rows()`  to bind the results into a single data frame.

Comment: @Limey Can you provide with a simple Example to illustrate your point.

Comment: No, I won't.  Because you have not accepted an answer to any of your questions and thus consistently fail to acknowledge the effort other put in to help you.  And because yesterday you were very rude (in my opinion, for no reason whatsoever) to someone who attempted to guide you in a comment.  You have enough information to get you started.  That's all I'm prepared to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to do it after long time and multiple tries, here is the complete code, you just need to add your API Key

```
# Get forecast data for a given city list
get_weather_forecaset_by_cities <- function(city_names) {
  df <- data.frame()
  for (city_name in city_names) {
    # Forecast API URL
    forecast_url <- "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast"
    # Create query parameters
    forecast_query <- list(q = city_name, appid = "***API Key***", units = "metric")
    # Make HTTP GET call for the given city
    forecast_response <- GET(forecast_url, query = forecast_query)
    # Note that the 5-day forecast JSON result is a list of lists. You can print the response to check the results
    forecast_json_list <- content(forecast_response, as = "parsed")
    results <- forecast_json_list$list
    result <- c(1:40)

    # Loop the json result
    for (x in result) {
      city <- c(city, city_name)
      # $weather is also a list with one element, its $main element indicates the weather status such as clear or rain
      weather <- c(weather, results[[x]]$weather[[1]]$main)
      # Get Visibility
      visibility <- c(visibility, results[[x]]$visibility)
      # Get current temperature
      temp <- c(temp, results[[x]]$main$temp)
      # Get min temperature
      temp_min <- c(temp_min, results[[x]]$main$temp_min)
      # Get max temperature
      temp_max <- c(temp_max, results[[x]]$main$temp_max)
      # Get pressure
      pressure <- c(pressure, results[[x]]$main$pressure)
      # Get humidity
      humidity <- c(humidity, results[[x]]$main$humidity)
      # Get wind speed
      wind_speed <- c(wind_speed, results[[x]]$wind$speed)
      # Get wind direction
      wind_deg <- c(wind_deg, results[[x]]$wind$deg)
      # Get forcast_datetime
      forecast_datetime <- c(forecast_datetime, results[[x]]$dt_txt)
    }

    # Add the R Lists into a data frame
    df <- data.frame(
      city = city, weather = weather,
      visibility = visibility,
      temp = temp,
      temp_min = temp_min,
      temp_max = temp_max,
      pressure = pressure,
      humidity = humidity,
      wind_speed = wind_speed,
      wind_deg = wind_deg,
      forecast_datetime
    )
  }

  # Return a data frame
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(httr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
> city_names <- c("Seoul", "Washington, D.C.", "Paris", "Suzhou")
> api_id<-'b0847c4a1554d3c63d46d0e9249500f0'
> main_df<-data.frame()
> for (city_name in city_names){
>   url<-str_glue("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&appid={api_id}&q={city_name}")
>   main_df<- bind_rows(main_df,get_weather_forecaset_by_cities(url))
> }
> 
> 
> get_weather_forecaset_by_cities <- function(url){
>   web_content <- httr::GET(url)
>   web_content <- content(web_content,"text")
>   json_data <- fromJSON(web_content, flatten = TRUE)
>   df <- as.data.frame(json_data)
>   return(df)
> }
```